# Set cookie in GraphQL mutation

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I need to update a cookie in GraphQL mutation using graphene and Django.

My first idea was to add cookie to context (which is request) and then set it in middleware.

I have a very simple mutation that looks like that:

```
class SetWantedCookieMutation(graphene.Mutation):

    class Arguments:
        wanted_cookie = graphene.String(required=True)

    ok = graphene.Boolean(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, wanted_cookie):
        # set cookie here 
        info.context.wanted_cookie = wanted_cookie

        return SetWantedCookieMutation(ok=True)
```

And Django Middleware is that:

```
class CookieMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if (hasattr(request, 'wanted_cookie')):
            response.set_cookie('wanted_cookie', request.wanted_cookie)
        return response
```

But I cannot get `wanted_cookie` in my `CookieMiddleware`.

Any ideas how to set cookie in mutation/moddlewere?
Or what are other ways to set cookie through graphene mutation?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to check the operation name in the json of the request:

```
class CookieMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def generate_cookie(self, user):
        # Generate a cookie (probably with the user)

    def request_has_cookie_mutation(self, request):
        # Returns true if the request's operation is SetWantedCookieMutation
        if len(request.body) != 0 and 'operationName' in json.loads(request.body):
            return json.loads(request.body)['operationName'] == 'SetWantedCookieMutation'
        return False

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if (self.request_has_cookie_mutation(request)):
            new_cookie = self.generate_cookie(request.user)
            response.set_cookie('wanted_cookie', new_cookie)
        return response
```

Note that it looks like you're using a version of Django pre-1.10 and [should consider upgrading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware).